# Developer use of "Taptic Engine" on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, apple-watch

According to Apple's press info about the release of iOS 8.2 and Xcode 6.2 found [here](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2014/11/18Developers-Start-Designing-Apps-for-Apple-Watch.html), they mention developers being able to use the new technologies presented with the Apple Watch:

> With the iOS 8.2 beta SDK, developers can now start using WatchKit to
>   create breakthrough new apps, Glances and actionable notifications
>   designed for the innovative Apple Watch interface and work with new
>   technologies such as Force Touch, Digital Crown and **Taptic Engine**.

After combing through the WatchKit framework documentation, I have found no mention of using the Taptic Engine. Is there a way for developers to use it? Perhaps they haven't implemented that yet and it may come in a later update for iOS 8.2, but I don't think this is the case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently in watchOS 2 beta 1, you can now use the `WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Click)` API to play haptic feedback on your Watch App.

You can find a full guide here on how to use this new API: http://www.sneakycrab.com/blog/2015/6/22/haptic-feedback-with-the-taptic-engine-in-watchkit-and-watchos-2-wkinterfacedevice-and-wkhaptic

Answer (score 7):

Direct access to the Taptic Engine is not possible with the WatchKit framework. Taptic feedback would come as a result of your app (for example) receiving a push notification.

Of course, if you'd like this feature, please file a request for it at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Could a local notification also trigger tactic feedback?